# Twitter archive data downloading is blocked?

Tags: twitter, twitter-archive

[image]

Hello, I applied to download twitter data but It says, "The download your data feature is unavailable right now. Try again at a later date." error message when I try. Would be very interesting to know if it's only my account or a global problem."What can I do?

Comment: I am also having this issue this morning. I do not have a computer of my own. I requested the data and got the notification that it is ready over the weekend. Today I am at the library to download it and getting the same error.